# Scraping 'Artsy' using rvest

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get information from [Artsy](https://www.artsy.net/collect?additional_gene_ids%5B0%5D=painting) using rvest package of R.   I want to get information on name of painting, year, price, place (name of gallery, auction etc.), name of artist, and materials that are used. Information on material is provided in inside page of each painting. Codes that I tried to use are provided below:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

get_material = function (painting_link) {
  painting_page = read_html (painting_link)
  material = painting_page %>% html_nodes('h2+ .kPqROo') %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(material)
}

for(page_result in 2:3) {
  
  link = paste0 ("https://www.artsy.net/collect?page=", page_result, "&additional_gene_ids%5B0%5D=painting") 
  page = read_html(link)
  
  painting_name_year = page %>%  html_nodes("#main .kjRHrZ") %>% html_text()
  painting_link = page %>% html_nodes('#main .kjRHrZ') %>% html_attr("<div color="black60" font-family="sans" class="Box-sc-15se88d-0 Text-sc-18gcpao-0 kjRHrZ">\n<i>") %>% paste("https://www.artsy.net", ., sep="/")
  price = page %>%  html_nodes('.ibabyz') %>%  html_text()
  place = page %>% html_nodes('hWKLzd') %>% html_text()
  artist = page %>% html_nodes('.bQOCym .bQOCym') %>% html_text()
  material = sapply(painting_link, FUN=get_material, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
artsy <- data.frame(painting_name_year, price, place, artist)
view(artsy)
```

Code for painting_link, place, and material are not working. Moreover, one observation is repeating for 3 times. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try the code below?

Comment: I have tried but got an error in the last portion of the code. "Error in future_map_dfr(links, .f = get_listing_info) : 
  could not find function "future_map_dfr""

Comment: you need to install and import library purrr

Comment: Yes, purrr is already installed in R and I have imported the library as well. Still I am getting that error.

Comment: Oops. I meant furrr as shown in the reprex.

Comment: Installed it now. Worked properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the loop. First generate the start url list. Then, rather than scrape some info from landing pages, before visiting individual listing pages, you can instead, gather all the urls of the individual listings first.

Then, you can gain a little efficiency by working across more cpu cores and gathering the data you want from all the listings via a function call against each url.

**N.B.** As this operation is I/O bound you would likely see better efficiencies with an asynchronous method. If I can find a decent tutorial/reference on this I will maybe update this answer.

If you return a `tibble` of the desired info, from each listing url, via the function, you can generate a final `dataframe` by calling `future_map_dfr` on the listings links and user defined function.

```r
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> Warning: package 'xml2' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     pluck
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(jsonlite)
#> Warning: package 'jsonlite' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     flatten
library(furrr)
#> Warning: package 'furrr' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Loading required package: future
#> Warning: package 'future' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(stringr)


get_art_links <- function(link) {
  hrefs <- read_html(link) %>%
    html_nodes("[href*=artwork][class]") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    paste0("https://www.artsy.net", .)
  return(hrefs)
}


get_listing_json <- function(page) {
  data <- page %>%
    html_node('[type="application/ld+json"]') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    jsonlite::parse_json()
  return(data)
}


get_listing_info <- function(link) {
  page <- read_html(link)
  json <- get_listing_json(page)
  artist <- json$brand$name
  title <- page %>%
    html_node('[data-test="artworkSidebar"] h2 > i') %>%
    html_text()
  production_date <- json$productionDate
  material <- page %>%
    html_node('[data-test="artworkSidebar"] h2 + div') %>%
    html_text()
  width <- json$width
  height <- json$height
  place <- stringr::str_match(json$description, "from (.*?),")[, 2] 
  price <- json$offers$price
  currency <- json$offers$priceCurrency
  availability <- str_replace(json$offers$availability, "https://schema.org/", "")
  return(tibble(artist, title, production_date, material, width, height, place, price, currency, availability))
}


pages <- 2:3 %>% as.character()
urls <- sprintf("https://www.artsy.net/collect?page=%s&additional_gene_ids[0]=painting", pages)

links <- purrr::map(urls, get_art_links) %>%
  unlist()

no_cores <- future::availableCores() - 1
future::plan(future::multisession, workers = no_cores)
results <- future_map_dfr(links, .f = get_listing_info)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>